# jQuery serialize() returns an empty string

Tags: jquery, forms

There are a number of related/similar/same questions, but none of them have helped me find the solution.

I have a HTML table wrapped in a form. For each row in the table, there is a hidden row with the form controls for editing. I don't need to submit the whole form as it would include all values for all cells. So, using AJAX, I want to submit only the values for a single row. To do this, I have given each row an id attribute, then using jQuery I hook the row's submit button and retrieve the values for that row.

The problem is, neither `.serialize()` nor `.serializeArray()` return anything. Yet, all the controls have names and values. And, as far as I can tell, there is no problem with the DOM structure.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waldermort/7hvrf2tq/) reproducing the problem.

Can anybody point out the problem or suggest a way to get the name value pairs without having to loop the controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded
>   notation. It can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual
>   form controls, such as , , and : $( "input,
>   textarea, select" ).serialize();

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Does not work for `div` because it is not a form control such as input, select or textarea

```
$("#foobar").parent('form').serialize()
```

Or select the form elements that you want to serialize

```
$( "input" ).serialize();
```

**Also**

> you can for instance give the form an id and serialize that. – 
>   Timotheus Triebl

Comment: you can for instance give the form an id and serialize that.

Comment: Your suggestion of selecting the form doesn't really answer my question of submitting a partial form.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that it has to be form control element and not a div

Comment: Ahh, I just added the ':input' selector after the '#foobar' now it works. Update your answer and I'll mark is as accepted :)

Comment: Thats what I was trying to tell you from the documentations, only form controls can be used. or simply the form itself. I added that to the answer